# Is there an easy to use, simple FTP server for Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ftp

For the past couple of hours I've been meddling around with vsftpd and pro-ftpd and Apache (for WebDav) and I find that there is not one program which can simply be run from the cmd and automatically provide read-only access to the server. I am having a huge headache and the documentation provided isn't really helpful (but Apache tries with the errors).

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to something that helps.

TIA.

Edit:- I don't want to be able to edit anything and I want to have the whole system exposed via FTP. I have no concerns about security regarding this server.

Edit2:- I finally managed to get it to work with vsftpd, apparently the problem I've been having is that when I used the default and the anonymous accounts, they displayed only var/www/ftp so I created a new account with adduser ftpuser -d / ((and something from /etc/shells)) and this allowed that user account FTP access to the whole system, what I intended to do. Thanks for all the answers, and I'll leave this thread open if someone remembers or knows the full command I used.

Edit3:- usermod --home /var/www/ username from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94603/limit-ftp-access-only-to-the-var-www-with-vsftpd might work (or in this case usermod --home / username)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Ubuntu FTP Server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1722/basic-ubuntu-ftp-server)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following link to setup VSFTP few months back you can give it a try. The link is [here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-secure-sftp-server-in-linux.html)

Comment: Hello, That is the same server (vsftpd) I am talking about in my question. Thanks for your answer anyway.